# A gerund or use a regular noun: "critically analyzing" or "critical analyzing" or "critical analysis"?

Tags: nouns, gerunds

Which of these is correct or more natural?

> - One of my greatest strengths is **critically analyzing**.
> - One of my greatest strengths is **critical analyzing**.
> - One of my greatest strengths is **critical analysis**.

Comment: I believe they're all correct; *critical analysis* is more natural.

Comment: As is usually the case where there is a choice, the 'pure' noun choice emphasises the field etc, the _ing_-form the carrying out of the process. Though there can be a single event - general domain contrast (a broadcast / broadcasting).

Comment: If you write: One of my greatest strengths is x, you would want to use critical analysis. *The others are not technically wrong*, you would say them, but in writing one expects to see a direct object: One of my greatest strengths is critically analyzing policies and procedures. For example.

Answer (score 2):

The first of those really needs an object. *One of my greatest strengths is critically analyzing (something)*. Otherwise, the third would be the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest "one of my greatest strengths is the *critical analysis*", or "one of my distinctive features/characteristics is the *critical analysis*".

Answer (score 0):

As is usually the case where there is a choice, the 'pure' noun choice emphasises the field etc, the ing-form the carrying out of the process. Though there can be a single event - general domain contrast (a broadcast / broadcasting).